# How to get the moderators attention?

Tags: support, flags, moderators

Is there any quick way of getting the moderators attention?
Flagging stuff doesn't seem to get anywhere (I understand that this is a very high volume site)
I can't even flag the same thing twice, as I just get the message "You have already flagged this message....."

Comment: Look, you just received a mod's attention!

Comment: @ZerO actually not really, 5 ordinary users migrated without a moderator being involved.

Comment: It depends on *the kind of attention* you are flagging for. And why should your attention get priority? Can you give us an example?

Comment: post a couple of more questions like *this* and you will *surely* get their attention :P

Comment: _Why_ do you want to get a moderator's attention?

Comment: _"I can't even flag the same thing twice"_ why would you need to flag something more than once?

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is what I wanted to show him. The site is moderated by it's users. There is no strict line between user and mod. he doesn't understand that he get's attention, but maybe it is not the attention that he wants

Comment: @ZerO still, diamond moderator has much more abilities than ordinary users, no matter how much rep they got.

Comment: He was asking why his flags have no effect. obviously, you do not need to be a diamond mod to handle flags

Answer (score 5):

I believe I know the flag you're referring to. Four days ago, you flagged one of your posts, requesting deletion because sensitive information had been posted within it.

The problem was that a couple of people had taken the time to leave very detailed answers on that question. My default instinct is to preserve content, so I didn't want to delete that, and I didn't fully understand the security ramifications of what you posted (you didn't post people's names and social security numbers, for example). However, I recognize that this could have potentially been a problem for you.

Dealing with sensitive information while not allowing people to just take their ball and go home is a very tricky topic, which is [why I asked it of the SO moderator candidates last election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/220347#220347) and why I keep trying to tell people to [check things first before you post them here](https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/410442895842217984). Sometimes, I don't know what the right action is.

I didn't know exactly what to do here, so I moved on to other flags I did know how to process. Looking at this again, you seemed to indicate that you could anonymize the values in your main question, but that you wanted to delete because you couldn't do so for the answers. I went and edited the answers to match your question, so that we might be able to preserve the question and answers while removing this sensitive information.

If this is acceptable, let me know and we could have a community team member burn the original revisions of these posts, leaving behind the anonymized ones. If we can avoid deletion of good, detailed answers, I'd prefer that.

Comment: Looks like he anonymized it already http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24444280/3 so all that needs to be done is to burn the history.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the reply, yes I am ultimately just trying to anonymize some of the hostnames. In my defence, I'd just flown from UK to Sydney, so maybe trying regex with jetlag wasn't a good idea in the first place :-) I put my hands up and admit it should have been anonymized before posting, but if someone could go in and anonymize the replies (even just removing the tld xxxx.local) that would be a great help. So far my boss and the IT sec guys have been very patient.......

Comment: @KeithMuggleton - OK, I think I got all the .locals as well in the one answer. Take a look through there and see if I missed anything. I can replace anything else if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a quick way, it's the way you used - flagging.

But you better be flagging for a very good reason, otherwise your flag is going to get dismissed. If a flag is dismissed the moderator may enter a message, but they're not obligated to. Alternatively they may choose to dismiss your flag as helpful, which means they've seen it but deem that no further action is required.

You should also keep in mind that moderators are exception handlers, not hall monitors which you can have a general chit chat with. If you can catch one in a chat room then great, ask a question or draw their attention to something, but otherwise make sure you are flagging something that needs action. Remember that moderators are real people with real lives - they balance their unpaid work on Stack Overflow with their regular every day stuff, so they don't always have time to be gossiping with whoever happens to come along.

General questions can also be brought up here on Meta - don't be shy.